# Trying to switch different variables individually through Node Red

Tags: python, node.js, output, raspberry-pi3, node-red

I have code that is outputting an x value, a y value, a max value, a radius value, and a theta value within my Raspberry Pi that updates every second.

An example output looks like this below:

```
Highest Number: 31.9029
x: -15
y: 8
Radius: 17.0
Theta: -28.07
```

What I'm trying to do through Node Red on my Raspberry Pi is output only the Radius value and the Theta value separately.

I simply did this to test for simply my radius value:

```
timestamp -- 
exec (My Python Script, while the command is running, spawn mode is enabled) -- 
switch node (contains "Radius") -- 
debug
```

But my output is showing different things almost every single time.

One output

```
Radius:
```

Another output

```
y: 8
x: -15
```

Another output

```
y: 8
Radius: 17.9
Theta: 30.96
```

It's all pretty ugly. Is there a way to get these outputs in a better way on Node Red?

Answer (score 0):

Add `-u` to the python arguments to get the python runtime to not buffer output to stdout so that Node-RED can parse it nicely.